# ElasticBeanstalk deployment to different accounts based on branches in a single repository

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm a bit confused as to how to setup ElasticBeanstalk such that different branches of a repository can deploy to different environments, or even possibly different accounts.

For example, I have a repository which has a `development` and `production` branch. On `development` we might have features which get tested locally and merged to development. Stable development gets deployed to production.

Our AWS account structure is setup similarly - we have a production account and a development account only.

What I want to be able to do is exclusively use one repository to deploy to both accounts, just by switching branches. However, I don't know how to write the `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` file in order to do that properly, or whether it is even possible since the two accounts are separate.

I know that you can do something like

```
branch-defaults:
    dev:
        environment: "dev-environment"
```

But then there's a global setting which corresponds to the actual AWS key pair. Not sure what that does.

The other confusing part is how the `ebcli` works.

If I want to use different profiles I'm used to doing a command like `eb list --profile user1` or `eb list --profile user2` where the different profiles are setup in `~/.aws/credentials`, however this doesn't seem to allow me to access different environments on different accounts. For example, if I have a development and production account, `eb list` will still only show the production account environments because I'm guessing that's where I did `eb init` in the first place. When I switch branches, however, I would like to be able to switch to the AWS development account environnents so that my deployments are always synced.

It is also worth mentioning that when I first created the git repository there was only a development branch and a master branch, and the eb initialization was made with that in mind. I want to add a production branch now to the current repository and shift everything over, basically.

Is this possible to accomplish? Let me know if any clarity is needed.